# @OneToMany which is in fact OneToOne / @Formula with Parameters

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have a Table 
Products ( ProductId, Name ) and 
ProductPrices (ProductId, Market, Price)

ProductPrices has a compositeKey (ProductId, Market). For a given Market, a Product has 0..1 Prices in that Market.

### First approach @Formula

The Market is known at runtime, and can possibly be changed per request.
In an first attempt to model the ProductEntity I took an @Formula annotation, like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(...)
public class Product {
@Id
private int ProductId;

private String name;

@Formula("(SELECT TOP 1 Price FROM ProductPrices p WHERE p.ProductId = ProductId  AND p.Market='Berlin')")
private double price;
}
```

But obviously, the market is then hard-compiled as annotations need to be static final Strings. [ so no @Formula("..." + getCurMarket() ) ].

### Second approach, @OneToMany

Take a separate entity class for the prices, and reference them in the product entity as:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
private List<Price> price;
```

In a `getPrice()`, I could always return the first entry (there will never be more...) or nothing if the list is empty.

I then want to create a Predicate/Specification to use from within the ProductService. Example:

```
public static Specification<Product> marketEquals(final String market) {
    return new Specification<Product>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Product> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {

            CriteriaQuery<String> q = cb.createQuery(String.class);
            Root<Price> price = q.from(Price.class);
            return price.get("Market").in("Berlin");
        }
    };
}
```

However, that only results in a (and I tried writing "market", "Market", ...)

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'generatedAlias1.market' [select generatedAlias0 from ...backend.entities.Product as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias1.market in (:param0)]
```

### Third approach, Hibernate/JPA Filter

This time, I write in the product entity

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    @Filters( {
        @Filter(name="marketFilter", condition="Market = :market")
    } )
  private List<Price> price;
```

Again, I want to fill this filter in the ProductService, but I cannot gelt hold of the CurrentSession. I tried the Spring-way, adding an `@Autowired private SessionFactory sessionFactory;` and configuring it through

```
Filter filter =  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().enableFilter("marketFilter");
filter.setParameter("market", "Berlin" );
```

but I cannot get hold of the right context, as `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory`

*Who could advise on how to model the database schema as entities, or could point working solutions to approach 2 and 3 ? Thanks!*

Answer (score 1):

Second approach is actually correct.Try it changing your entities and creteria query.

Products table:

```
@Entity
@Table(...)
public class Product {
@Id
private int ProductId;

private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "products")
private List<ProductPrices> ProductPrices;
}
```

ProductPrices table:

```
@Entity
@Table(...)
public class ProductPrices {
@Id
private int ProductPriceId;

private String market;

private double price;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "product_id") //foreign key reference
private Product products
}
```

ProductService:

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
                CriteriaQuery<Product> qry = cb.createQuery(Product.class);
                Root<Product> root = qry.from(Product.class);
                Join<Product, ProductPrices> price = root.join("ProductPrices");
                List<Predicate> conditions = new ArrayList<>();
                conditions.add(cb.equal(price.get("products"), "Berlin"));

                TypedQuery<Product> typedQuery = em.createQuery(qry
                        .select(root)
                        .where(conditions.toArray(new Predicate[] {}))
                        .orderBy(cb.asc(root.get("Berlin")))
                        .distinct(true)
                );

return typedQuery;
```